# Apply the REL attibute automatically to posts using jQuery

Tags: jquery, children, blogger, colorbox

**Edited: I mean *grouping* as giving the same `REL` attibute to all `IMG`s in the same post, but each post has different `REL` as the example at the end of this question.**

So, I need to do the following:

```
<div id="Blog1" class="widget Blog">
<div class="blog-posts hfeed">
<div class="post hentry uncustomized-post-template">
<a name="8829400899632947948"/>
<div class="post-body entry-content">
<div id="8829400899632947948">
<div class="separator">

<a imageanchor="1" href="/images/outta.png">
<img src="/images/outta.png"/></a></div></div>

<div style="clear: both;"/>
</div>
<div class="post-footer">
</div></div></div></div>
```

I'm using jQuery and Colorbox. The first two `DIV`s are posts containers. I need to group the `IMG`s in each `<div class="post hentry uncustomized-post-template">` using the `REL` attribute, like:

> 1 - Post
>
> 1.1 - IMG - REL="group0"
>
> 1.2 - IMG - REL="group0"
>
> 1.3 - IMG - REL="group0"
>
> 1.4 - IMG - REL="group0"
>
> 2 - Post
>
> 2.1 - IMG - REL="group1"
>
> 3 - Post
>
> 3.1 - IMG - REL="group2"
>
> 3.2 - IMG - REL="group2"

I've tryied `HAS`, `PARENT > CHILDREN` and `CHILDREN()` from jQuery and `REL:` from Colorbox, but it seems I'm lacking somewhere in logic.

Could someone help me?

Comment: I've read over this three times and I still have no idea what you're talking about.  It'd help if you could clean up your code example with some indentation, and explain what you mean by "group" the img tags.

Comment: Edited Pointy. Sorry for my bad english. Maybe I ain't being as clear as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you mean?

```
// 'walk' through every element that has class 'post'
// passing the index of each element to variable i
$('.post').each(function(i) {
    // on `this` element, find all children img
    // to which add attribute 'rel' with a value of
    // 'group' concatenated with the parent's index (i)
    $(this).find('img').attr('rel', 'group' + i);
    });
```

*edit: add some comments, hope this help those new with jquery*